# Need to recursively parse SharePoint 2010 sites for JavaScript tags and output URL path to a file

Tags: powershell

I have a site with approx. 300+ sites.  The vast majority use JS and reference a jquery file that are either in the parent folder as the aspx file or site, or referencing a master jquery file in a designated spot.

The goal is to output the full URL of every file/site that has the `<script type="text/javascript">` tag to a txt file line by line.

I figured out how to recursively traverse the site, but I don't know how to parse for the text I'm looking for and how to output the results to a text file.  Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
function RecurseSite() {
    param([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$SiteIdentity)

    Write-Output "Site: $($SiteIdentity.Url)"

    if($SiteIdentity.Webs.Count -gt 0)
    {
        foreach($subWeb in $SiteIdentity.Webs)
        {
            RecurseSite -SiteIdentity $subWeb
        }
    }
}

$contentWebAppServices = (Get-SPFarm).services |
 ? {$_.typename -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"}

foreach($webApp in $contentWebAppServices.WebApplications)
{
    Write-Output "Web Application: $($webApp.name)"
    foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
    {
        Write-Output "Site Collection: $($siteColl.Url)"
        RecurseSite -SiteIdentity $($siteColl.RootWeb)
    }
}function RecurseSite() {
    param([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$SiteIdentity)

    Write-Output "Site: $($SiteIdentity.Url)"

    if($SiteIdentity.Webs.Count -gt 0)
    {
        foreach($subWeb in $SiteIdentity.Webs)
        {
            RecurseSite -SiteIdentity $subWeb
        }
    }
}

$contentWebAppServices = (Get-SPFarm).services |
 ? {$_.typename -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"}

foreach($webApp in $contentWebAppServices.WebApplications)
{
    Write-Output "Web Application: $($webApp.name)"
    foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
    {
        Write-Output "Site Collection: $($siteColl.Url)"
        RecurseSite -SiteIdentity $($siteColl.RootWeb)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: you can traverse through Pages library in each site, do the request for the item URL and parse the content. However, if you want to check really every page even those including lists, libraries and forms, this will not work.

You also can try to use SP statistics to get the urls of pages and use them as feed for your parsing.